# alter dictionary object in local variable

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to both remove the method from the method ArrayList and check to see if the ArrayList is empty in one lookup.
This uses two look ups.

```
private Map<String, List<Method>> events;

public void removeEvent(String eventName, Method method){
    try{
        events.get(eventName).remove(method);
        if(events.get(eventName).size() == 0){
            events.remove(eventName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

As you can see it looks up the ArrayList of methods to remove a method then looks it up again to see if its length is zero then looks it up again to remove the HashMap entry. Is their a way to combine at least the first two look ups?

Comment: I would guess there is not, as the Map does not know on runtime what you want to do if the  value (which is a collection) of a key is empty. You could write your own Map implementation to do that. But still somewhere you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You may change it to this way:

```
List<Method> methods = events.get(eventName);
if (methods == null) {
    return;
}
methods.remove(method);
if (methods.isEmpty()) {
    events.remove(eventName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might be helpful in your case.
It does not require to lookup second times to check the size of list.

```
public void removeEvent(String eventName, Method method){
    try{
        List<Method> methods = events.get(eventName);
        methods.remove(method);
        if(methods.size() == 0){
            events.remove(eventName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```